# Why does Geoserver WMS not work in GeoExt?

Tags: openlayers-2, wms, geoext

Geoserver URL

```
{http://localhost:8090/geoserver/Test/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=Test:B901_AS&styles=&bbox=638500.0,5309500.0,639000.0,5310000.0&width=512&height=512&srs=EPSG:4326&format=application/openlayers}
```

HTML code

```
<html>
<head>

<title> A Basic GeoExt Page </title>
<script src="ext-3.4.0/adapter/ext/ext-base.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="ext-3.4.0/ext-all.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ext-3.4.0/resources/css/ext-all.css"></link>
<script src="OpenLayers-2.12/OpenLayers.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="GeoExt/lib/GeoExt.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="GeoExt/resources/geoext-all-debug.css"></link>

<script type="text/javascript">
    Ext.onReady(function() {

        var map = new OpenLayers.Map();
        var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
            "Global Imagery",
            "http://localhost:8090/geoserver/Test/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=Test:B901_AS&styles=&bbox=638500.0,5309500.0,639000.0,5310000.0&width=512&height=512&srs=EPSG:4326&format=application/openlayers",
            {layers: "bluemarble"}
        );
        map.addLayer(layer);

        new GeoExt.MapPanel({
            renderTo: 'gxmap',
            height: 400,
            width: 600,
            map: map,
            title: 'A Simple GeoExt Map'
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="gxmap"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

What is the problem? Pls help me.

Comment: Indeed, what is the problem? Exactly what goes wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your projections are wrong.

```
bbox=638500.0,5309500.0,639000.0,5310000.0&width=512&height=512&srs=EPSG:4326
```

says that you want a map in lat/lon (epsg:4326) while your bounding box says that you want a map in meters (? epsg:900913?). GeoServer has given you exactly what you asked for - a very small map somewhere in the lower left corner (-180,-90 180,90) of the larger image requested.